# How is memory leak avoided with INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Tags: wpf

It's not clear for me how WPF DataBinding gets detached from PropertyChanged event of the object implementing INotifyProprtyChanged interface. Otherwise binding source holds the reference to the control and it's not released.

So am I responsible for clearing all bindings of the view to let GC clear it or is  this somehow automated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF uses the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) to address this problem. So no, you don't need to release the bindings manually. It will be done once your Control gets unloaded.

Comment: Hum.. You made me read about WEP once again more thoroughly. Thanks.